# Append two data frames created by two functions in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have two functions, func_1 (which reads the csv file in a dataframe) & func_2 (which reads another csv file in a dataframe). Now I want to stack the two dataframes. I have the below code:

```
def func1():
  df = pd.read_csv("a.csv")
  return df

def func2():
  df = pd.read_csv("b.csv")
  return df
```

Now how do I combine/append the two dataframes created in each function

Comment: Read [this section of the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) about how to merge dataframes.

Comment: This might do the trick: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the shape of the data frames and how you want to combine them. It could be:

```
df1 = func1()
df2 = func2()
merged = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Or it could be:

```
df1 = func1()
df2 = func2()
df1.append(df2, sort=False)
```

Depending on their shape. For example we can stack them on top of one another if they've got the same column titles:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], columns=['a','b','c'])
print(df1)

>    a  b  c
> 0  1  2  3

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[4, 5, 6]], columns=['a','b','c'])
print(df2)

>    a  b  c
> 0  4  5  6

df1.append(df2)
print(df1)

>    a  b  c
> 0  1  2  3
> 0  4  5  6
```

Or if they've got some different column names we might concatinate them and pandas will fill NaNs in the gaps:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], columns=['a','b','c'])
print(df1)

>    a  b  c
> 0  1  2  3

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[4, 5, 6]], columns=['b','c','d'])
print(df2)

>    b  c  d
> 0  4  5  6

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)
print(df3)

>      a  b  c    d
> 0  1.0  2  3  NaN
> 0  NaN  4  5  6.0
```

As you can imagine there are loads of different permutations, merging across different axes or maintaining the index numbering and so on and so forth, so really you need to [read the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) to work out what's best for you.